# Redis vs Class variables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, redis, sidekiq

Im using Sidekiq, Redis, Websocket-rails inside of Rails. With sidekiq having server-side Class. Now, when adding more functionality, i cant anymore use instance variables inside my Sidekiq Class's methods, i need to share information between methods. Sidekiq class also inherits from Websocket class, to be available websockets.
Right now, i have 2000/per second data change for objects. Using 95% instance variables, 5% pushing/getting from Redis, to make lower I/O. 
Im considering, using class variables or making all 100% on Redis. Im not sure about or it wont overload my background jobs with that big data transfer count, which goes bigger with every new client. I'm using heroku free Dyno, dont want to buy better server yet. But using class variables would be less I/O, and probably unsafe, becouse it inherits from Websocket-rails? Im doing this project partly to show something to employers, that i can program, to get my 1-st IT job. I care how they react to those class variables. What employers would say about class variables? And which one to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class variables have their places, if they represent a concept that is unchangeable and should live as a definition of something, like a configuration throughout the application, or some fundamental multiplier of a part of the application domain/business.

But, just because things are unchanging, that doesn't mean they have to be a class variable. You can have an instance of a class to be always setup with the same values, and then share the instance. Kind of like a singleton, but not necessarily being a singleton, just being a widely shared variable that is part of the input on the start of a given process.

So instead of using Sidekiq to store data for this unchanging thing, and rather than using class variables, you can achieve a cleaner design by doing something like

```
class ImportantThing
  def initialize(name, other_property)
    @name = name
    @other_property = other_property
  end

  # Other methods you wish to define the behavior of the thing
end
```

then you can

```
the_important_thing = ImportantThing.new("foobar", 3.46)
do_important_process(the_important_thing)
```

then as far as the important process you are running is concerned, the important thing is anything that behaves like a important thing, and it doesn't matter if it is a globally setup or ever unchanging.

This makes for a easy to test architecture which is generally a sign of clear and decoupled design.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely use instance variables in your Sidekiq worker.  You cannot use **class or class-instance** variables.

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(a, b)
    @a = a # instance variable, no problem!

    @@a = a # class variable, big problem!
    self.set_a(a)
  end

  def self.set_a(a)
    @a = a  # class instance variable, big problem!
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, i checked on my app, if i use class variable with sidekiq, and additionaly there have websocket methods to change this class variable, it doesn't change. So i just did redis datastore as variable.